# Was George peeping on Loraine?

Tags: back-to-the-future

I've included the video for the respective (well, it's not very respectful :P) scene below:

We see George is a peeping tom as Marty so astutely points out, but my question is **who** is George peeping on?  I've drawn a diagram below of the scene.

[image: Diagram]

Is that Loraine's house, meaning it is Loraine George is peeping on (suggesting he liked her before they met), or is it someone else?  Bear in mind that **we do not see the woman's face**

Comment: Yes, it was Lorraine.  And who can blame the guy?  She's smoking hot.

Comment: @WadCheber do you have any proof of this?

Comment: Marty's grandpa hits Marty with his car, gets out, and yells to his wife.  She was obviously very close by at the time, but she wasn't in the car.  Therefore, either, by pure luck, she was standing near the location of an accident she didn't know would happen, or the accident happened in front of her house.  That makes it all but certain that George was peeping at Lorraine.

Comment: @WadCheber I don't see how that makes it so certain at all?  We don't actually know how long a time transpires before Lorraine and/or her mother reacts.  Presumably either house in my diagram is Lorraine's house, but I'm not sure, as we don't actually see the face of the person George is peeping on

Comment: @N_Soong - You're missing the point.  The accident happened so close to their house that Grandpa was able to shout to his wife inside.  Also, 1985 Lorraine McFly said the accident happened outside her house.  Also, we know that her room was on the second floor of the house, because when Marty falls out of the bed, Grandma shouts "Lorraine, are you up there?".  Lorraine also tells Marty he is in her bedroom.  George was looking at a hot girl in an upstairs window.  Grandma is not hot.  There are no other women in the house.  Ergo, George was peeping at Lorraine.

Comment: @N_Soong - I don't remember any other scenes where Marty is anywhere near the house. I think it was so obvious that the producers didn't think it needed to be explained.

Comment: @N_Soong - I found something better.

Comment: Your Diagram is WRONG. He's peeping into the house across from the Tree base. His bike is across the street from the house Gramps is yelling into.

Comment: @cde I don't think so - we see later in that clip that the car is on the road and George goes across *towards* Loraine's house to get his bike which is **by the tree**

Comment: Marty and George were looking/facing the same direction. George falls in front of Marty, in the same direction. Marty pushes him towards that same direction, closer to the house with the babe. The branch George is on is stretching from the base towards the Babe over the road. Note the door in the background at 0:37 when Marty looks across the street at the Babe, and 0:52 when he runs away from the bike and that same door, towards that same way he was looking. Which is the same way Gramps is yelling at the end.

Comment: @cde oh - my bad!

Comment: I was just about to say cde was wrong, but then I noticed that the diagram had already been corrected.  Yeah, the old version was wrong.  The new one is right.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the [script](http://web.archive.org/web/20060216092148/http://www.bttf.com/ImageFolio3_files/gallery/Scripts/19841012.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> She turns on the bedside lamp.  **It's the same girl George was spying on**, and **Marty recognizes her** just as we do...
>
> Marty:  Oh my god.  You're...  You're my...  You're my... my...
>
> Lorraine:  My name's Lorraine.  Lorraine Baines.

Even without this information, it seemed pretty clear from the scene itself.

When Grandpa Baines hits Marty, he gets out of the car and shouts to his wife.  This means that the accident happened directly outside the house.  In fact, 1985 Lorraine McFly said that George McFly was hit by her father's car in front of their home. The girl was in an upstairs bedroom window.  We know that Lorraine's bedroom is upstairs, because when Marty wakes up, she tells him he is in her room;  then Marty falls out of the bed, and we hear Grandma Baines shout "Lorraine, are you up there?"  The woman in the window was very attractive, and fairly young, but certainly not a child.  Grandma Baines is not attractive, and there are no other women or girls of roughly the right age in the house.  It must have been Lorraine.

I think we're supposed to find it funny that Marty's dad used to peep on Marty's mom.  It is also a bit creepy, of course, but therein lies the humor.  Marty's dad is a pervert.

Comment: “Grandma Baines is not attractive” You take that back.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - she ain't. Not compared to Marty's gf :)

Comment: @DVK: “Not compared to Marty's gf”. [Which](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claudia_Wells) [one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elisabeth_Shue)?

Comment: So the real question should be *Why was her father driving **by** the house rather than pulling into the driveway or parking spot?*

Answer (score 1):

if you look at where the scenes were filmed the house that was identified as the Baines house is the same as the house the scene where George McFly aimed his binoculars.   After watching that movie dozens of times I finally made the connection.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Would it be possible for you to add screenshot pictures to make clear that these are the same house? This looks like it has the makings of a good answer, but would be better with some more canonical proof :-)

Answer (score -1):

I say no way. The room that he is looking into that none of you mention had green paint on the walls. But Lorraine’s room has flower wallpaper.

Comment: Note that the pattern on the wallpaper is pretty small, too small to show up in the view from outside, and the overall colour will have a completely different rendering in sunlight (more blue) instead of incandescent light (more yellow/red).  I would say this is not at all conclusive.